# Orchard cms custom settings

Tags: orchardcms

How do I create a custom form only for admin to enter 2 setting values.

1. Admin should be able to enter number of published sites.
2. Admin should be able to enter number of paid sites.

The site then uses these values to display on UI. Is there anyway in Orchard CMS to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. In Orchard, settings are a content item of type Site. You can extend them like you extend any content type, by adding parts and fields. Look at any example of module with settings.

Comment: Hi.. I am able to add values that I wanted to add. But I don't see them in the WorkContext. How do I see them?

Comment: `workContext.CurrentSite.As<WhateverTheTypeOfThePartYouAddedIs>()`

Comment: As an update, for those that get into this, you can follow the Orchard doc [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Adding-custom-settings).